# App works perfectly fine on Samsung phone but doesn't work on LG

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app-store, flashlight

I've created a simple Android flashlight app that seems to be working on any Samsung device that I've tried it on but it doesn't seem to work with the LG G series phones. I've tested it on the LG G3, G4 and G5.

The app loads up the mainActivity perfectly fine, but when the flashlight button is clicked, nothing happens. I've plugged it in to see if there's some sort of error message that comes up when I attempt to use the flashlight, but no error occurs.

Is this a common problem between device manufacturers? I've done a bit of research and from what I've gathered as long as I code my app properly towards each Android OS, I shouldn't have a problem.

I've had some LG devices work, while others simply don't. Both phones have been on the same Android Version and on the same network. Anyone else experience this?

**EDIT**

I learned that you have to setPreviewTexture(0) on some phones in order for the app to turn the torch on properly. However, now I'm running into the issue of the app lagging when trying to use it with burst mode.

Comment: What your debugger is saying?

Comment: Not getting any sort of error. I run through the debugger and the camera opens perfectly fine. Not sure what else to try from here.